# Installing php 5.5.4 on Debian 6.0.1 - "Undefined reference to gzopen64@ZLIB_1.2.3.3"

Tags: debian, php5, libxml

I'm trying to install/upgrade the version of PHP we're using on our internal server at work.  Doing it from the tarball from php.net and when it comes time to run ./configure I get this error:

checking whether libxml build works... no
configure: error: build test failed.  Please check the config.log for details.

The config.log has this to say about libxml:

> configure:22189: checking whether libxml build works
>   configure:22216: cc -o conftest -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden   conftest.c
>
> ```
>     -lrt -lm -ldl -lnsl  -lxml2 >&5
> ```
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so: undefined reference >to `gzopen64@ZLIB_1.2.3.3'

I've already tried doing a pretty basic update of libxml from apt and installing specifically zlib 1.2.3.3 from a tarball on http://zlib.net/fossils/ and frankly that's me all out of ideas.

**EDIT** Solved.  Updating to the latest version of zlib rather than using 1.2.3.3  has fixed the issue.